# Does gcloud app versions delete remove instances immediately?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When I run `gcloud app versions delete` ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/delete)) it often takes a while (2-5 minutes) to delete a version.

When that command is finished do that mean the version is totally deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here because the inconsistent behavior took a while to debug.

When you delete a Google App Engine **Standard** instance using the CLI it seems to be deleted pretty much immediately. If you check operations by running `gcloud app operations list` it won't be in the pending state for more than a second or two.

However, when you delete a Google App Engine **Flexible** instance using the CLI it is still in a pending state for 5-10 minutes after the the CLI command seems to have been finished.

I reached out to GCP support about this and they said:

> It is normal that the version may still be completing some steps in the background shortly after the delete command is complete and remain in PENDING state for a short time.

Edit: I have since wrote a script to wait for GAE operations to finish before moving on. It's available here: https://gist.github.com/RayBB/0b442641ad740701ef5c96f5f9ef9dd9

Comment: You shoukd always check. It is possible that instances of old versions just never die